# step function which is function of the variables

Tags: integration

I know how to handle **unit step functions**, but I got confused of how to do the integration when the **step function** is itself a **function of the variable**.

As for example: $I= \int dx* \theta(g(x)-g(x_{0}) ) $

where, g(x) is a function of x.

**=====================================================================**

I am interested in the general case of **function of multi variables** ,

As for example: $I= \int f(x,y,z)*dx*dy*dz* \theta(g(x,y,z)-g(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0}) ) $

where, f(x,y,z) & g(x,y,z) are functions of x,y,z.

I believe that handling this multivariable case would be similar to the single variable one.

**=====================================================================**

Any reference of handling such **step functions** that are just not **unit step functions** ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you handle these type of questions in 1D?

Comment: well, the answer to your question is, I do not know. I think instead of asking the solution for multivariable case I should have asked for single variable case. Let me edit the post. Thank you